# "Invalid" iphone string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string

I'm converting data (from a web page) to a string).  The basic code works (but there's been some subtle change somewhere  - maybe on server).

NSLog shows the expected string (maybe 1000 chars long).  However, when I float over responseString, it shows "Invalid".  Worse, parsing with componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet does not work.

Ideas?

```
NSString *responseString;
responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"responsestring ='%@'",responseString]);
if ([responseString compare:@""] != NSOrderedSame) {
    lines = [responseString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@";"]];
```

Comment: Just a note that you can use equalsTo: instead of compare: to compare strings. Then you don't have to equate it to NSOrderedSame.

Comment: rein - thanks for the tip.  Went with isEqual.

Comment: Also, your NSLog doesn't need to have the stringWithFormat stuff. In fact, that would be bad.

NSLog(@"responseString='%@'",responseString) will do what you want, since it automatically has the formatting. 

(The reason why it's bad is that the responseString, if it has a % in it, may cause you to crash since you could be passing in @"responseString='Some Random Value with % in it'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may happen when the configuration is set to "Release" rather than "Debug" I think.

Answer (score 0):

Do not trust what the debugger says, it is not accurate, this has happened to me and took me a while to realise that the xcode debugger is not always right and should not be trusted, so i no longer trust the debugger and i use nslog statements whenever it tries to tell me something is invalid. So dont worry about it it happens, and when it happened to me I was also parsing responses from some webservice.

Comment: Dead on.  I went back and realized I set version to "release".  The debugger should provide different values like "unknown - using release version" if it can't figure out the value.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear -- my experience with seeing "Invalid" in the debugger means that the reference is to an already-released object.

Your question and the comments below seem to suggest that you are thinking "Invalid" is an actual string value -- but are you sure you don't just have a memory management probably?